# Combine multipolygons in feature collection while keeping boundaries in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geojson, union, borders

This problem has been driving me absolutely crazy for a week now:

I have a map of a lot (1911) of districts. I need to add them all to a map, which is pretty heavy because each one requires a separate overlay, so I am trying to fit them all into one.

To do this, I was hoping to combine all the multipolygons in my feature collection (in a GeoJSON file). I've been trying to do all different kinds of merges, but they all end up erasing the boundaries, rather unsurprisingly.

Here is part of the map that I am working with:

[image: US districts map]

Each of the districts above is a separate multi polygon.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24184927/postgis-merge-multipolygons-and-keeping-boundaries) question asks something very similar to what I am asking, but it is about PostGIS, and I have no clue how to use PostGIS; from what I've read and attempted, there is a steep (and setup) learning curve.

How can I merge the features in a map while retaining their boundaries in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to install a nightly of QGIS 3.0, and use the "Collect geometries" algorithm. It does exactly what you're after!

Comment: According to the [roadmap](https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/roadmap.html#location-of-prereleases-nightly-builds) that build will not be available until 2/23/18. Am I missing something? Is it located elsewhere?

Comment: You can download "nightly" or "weekly" prereleases - the current ones are very stable and can be safely used until the final release next week!